# Как разместить панель инструментов Tool Windows в PyCharm-e справа?

Tags: pycharm

По умолчанию, панель инструментов Tool Windows (где выводится консоль, результаты выполнения кода и др) в пайчарме находится внизу, под панелью с кодом.
Вопрос: как разместить эту панель справа от панели кода? Такая возможность есть?
В настройках не нашел, в инструкции тоже не написано.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Поторопился с вопросом, но методом тыка обнаружил, что в настройке этой панели есть выбор Move To -> Right Top.